# Run Sql Script File With Passing database name from C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I have a `SQL Script` File Which contains database creation, its related tables creation and other things. The database name is decided from client side. So is there any way that I can run that script file where Database name is passed from my code?

I know a way where i take some special pattern in place of database name and then in c# code I do replace it with client side added Database name. But is there any better way to do it?

Comment: I think you can read that text and execute it

Comment: @brykneval but database name will be given by user.

Comment: String.Format("Create database {0} ......", userinput);

Comment: @brykneval All script are written in a file.

Comment: you can load the text from the file, and even edit the file as Create database {0} so that it will  be easy when you impport

Answer (score 1):

If you are creating tables on the fly in your application, you will missed some fundamentals about database design. In a relational database, the set of tables and columns are supposed to be constant. They may change with the installation of new versions, but not during run-time.

You can check it [here](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html#Cre_tbl)

```
create proc createdb @dbname sysname
as
declare @sql nvarchar(max)
set @sql = 'create database ' + QUOTENAME(@dbname)
exec (@sql)
```

Here you can pass @dbname as parameter